# IDEA unable to run JavaScript script using NodeJs on Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA tries to run following command.

```
/usr/sbin/node --debug-brk=39773 --nolazy calculate.js
```

It fails because "node" is not "nodejs" on Ubuntu.
How do I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

1. In IDEA go to Run->Edit Configurations.
2. Change "Node interpreter" field to "/usr/bin/nodejs".